# DatagramSocket not receiving some packets on Android 9

Tags: android, sockets, datagram, caller-id

I want to receive callerId callbacks in my Android application. I've followed an example provided by it's creators which is available [here](https://github.com/callerid/exampleApp_android_marshmellow_up).

My listening function looks like this (exact copy but in Kotlin):

```
private fun startListening() {
        val socket = DatagramSocket(null)
        val address = InetSocketAddress("255.255.255.255", 3520)
        socket.reuseAddress = true
        socket.broadcast = true
        socket.bind(address)

        var looping = true
        var buffer = ByteArray(65507)

        while (looping) {
            val dp = DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.size)
            try {
                log.debug("Waiting for call")
                socket.receive(dp)

                val recString = String(dp.data, 0, dp.length)

                log.debug("Received new message: $recString")
                _callReceivedLive.postValue(recString)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                log.error("Exception in CallerIdListener", e)
                looping = false
            }
        }
    }
```

After installing it on device with Android 5.1.1 Version everything seems fine. Every single call I mock using Ethernet Emulator is received by the application. 
Now after firing this app on Samsung Galaxy Tab with Android Version 9 it only receives like 30% of calls.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've tested it on Xiaomi device with Android 9 too.. same thing happend. I've tried changing different settings on both devices (Samsung one had some settings related to `CallerId`) but it didn't help. I've been also checking if the broadcast was actually send on my PC. It was received by it every time.. so it seems like there is a problem with new Android devices?

Comment: Thanks. D'oh! I'm having UDP issues that only affects some devices. :-/ Hey, if 30% get through, what if you sent the packet 3x?

Comment: I have no control over device which sends packets. And it's not like every third packet is caught. It really acts randomly.

Comment: I see. All the best. Hopefully you find a solution.